# convert string yyyyMM to Mon - yyyy

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to convert a string which is in yyyyMM format to Mon-yyyy format. For example, `201606` should return `Jun - 2016`. 
What I tried is

```
string strVal = "201606";
string monthYear = DateTime.Parse(strVal.ToString("MMM-yyyy")).ToString();
```

Ain't working. Please help.

Comment: What does "Ain't working" entail? errors? invalid results?

Comment: What do you think `strVal.ToString("MMM-yyyy")` does? Have you looked?

Comment: [Custom Date and time formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"201606"` isn't a standard date format, so you need to do 2 things:

1. Use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the correct `DateTime`.
2. Call `ToString("MMM-yyyy")` on the DateTime to get the new formatted date:

   ```
   string strVal = "201606";
   string monthYear = DateTime.ParseExact(strVal, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("MMM-yyyy");
   Console.WriteLine(monthYear);
   ```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
string strVal = "201606";
string monthYear = DateTime.ParseExact(strVal, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MMM-yyyy");
```

First you had to convert your string to `DateTime` then back to `string`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `DateTime.ParseExact` first:

```
DateTime yearMonth = DateTime.ParseExact("201606", "yyyyMM", null);
string monthYear = yearMonth.ToString("MMM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use ParseExact.

```
string strVal = "201606";
string monthYear = DateTime.ParseExact(strVal, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MMM-yyyy");
```